# Passing return value of function to decorator

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am relatively new to decorators.

My doubt here is can we pass return value of the function to the decorator function. Adding pseudo code

```
@dec(a = x)
def fun():
    x = 25
    return x
# My decorator function
def dec(a = x)
    print a
```

Comment: It's unclear to me what you want to do. This currently doesn't work, right? But how should it work?

Comment: Yes, This does not work. I need to pass the return value from the function to the decorator function. Is it possible ??

Comment: Of course, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7201715/how-change-a-functions-return-with-decorator-in-python

Comment: It's unclear what the expected output is. An example would help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to do something like that:

```
# My decorator function
def dec(func):
    def func_wrapper(a):
        print (a, " :Decorator value a")
        return func(a)
    return func_wrapper

@dec
def func(a):
    x = 25
    print(x, " :Function value x")
    return x


func(5)
# Output:
#  5  :Decorator value a
#  25  :Function value x
```