# Using decorator to change the return value of a method

Tags: python, decorator

I have a `TextBox` and a `Button`. When the user hits <kbd>Enter</kbd>, I want the specific button related to the `TextBox` to be clicked. `TextBox` and `Button` are classes. I am passing `Button` instance into the `TextBox`, so that we know one should be clicked. `Button` is a class with 2 methods `click()` and `autoclick()`.

What I want is for `autoclick()` to check if <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is being pressed and make `click()` return `True` if it is. I tried using decorators and wrote this toy program to demonstrate exactly what I tried.

```
class Button:
    def click(self):
        return False

    def autoclick(self, func, *args):
        def wrapper():
            func(*args)# This function needes events as it argumnet
            return True
        return wrapper

b = Button()
class TextBox:
    def __init__(self, button=None):
        self.button = button

    def box(self):
        if enterPressed:
            if self.button is not None:
                self.button.autoclick(self.button.click, events)()


tb = TextBox(button=b)
while True:
    tb.box()
    if b.click():
        print("this needs to be printed when user hits enter")
```

I don't get any errors but it simply doesn't work.

Comment: `tb.button` is always None, so `self.button.autoclick(self.button.click, events)` will never be executed.

Comment: this question was already asked so feel free to take a look into [7201715](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7201715/how-to-change-a-functions-return-using-a-decorator)

Comment: @Jack Song Sorry, b was meant to be passed to TextBox, i updated the question

Comment: another problem is that the decorator is never actually called. `self.button.autoclick(self.button.click, events)` just returns the function handler but does not run the function.

Comment: Ah, yes my bad again, i updated the question,  sorry

Comment: You need to pass `*args` (ie. `events`), too.

Comment: where?. Sorry, i am extremely new to decorators

Comment: I am passing events to self.button.autoclick

Comment: `self.button.autoclick(self.button.click, events)(events)`. `autoclick` actually needs no `*args` as parameters, but `wrapper` needs.

Comment: Just tried that. Threw an error, which i solved by adding *args to wrapper definition. Now it doesn't throw error, but doesn't do anything either. Just like before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may know what you want to do now.

Try this out. This is how we usually use decorators.

```py
class Button:
    @autoclick # this is how decorators are used.
    def click(self):
        return False

    def autoclick(self, func):
        def wrapper(*args):
            func(*args)# This function needes events as it argumnet
            return True
        if enterPressed:
            return wrapper
        else:
            return func
```

Comment: No, this didn't work. I think it's because we are only printing something if b.click itself returns True not autoclick

Comment: Yes. It is always False now.

Comment: It says autoclick missing one required positional argument "func"

Answer (score 0):

I think the following part is needed to be modified

> ```py
> class TextBox:
>    def __init__(self, button=None):
>        self.button = button
>
>    def box(self):
>        if enterPressed:
>            if self.button is not None:
>                self.button.autoclick(self.button.click, events)()
> ```

to something like:

```py
class TextBox:
    def __init__(self, button=None):
        self.button = button

    def box(self):
        if enterPressed:
            if self.button is not None:
                self.button.click = self.button.autoclick(self.button.click)  # this line is changed
```

---

**UPDATE**

I guess maybe you are supposed to mean something like the following:

```py
class Button:
    def _click(self):  # Maybe this method have events as parameters?
        return False

    def click(self):
        return self._click()

    def autoclick(self):
        def wrapper(*args):
            self._click(*args)  # This function needs events as it arguments
            self.click = self._click
            return True

        self.click = wrapper


class TextBox:
    def __init__(self, button=None):
        self.button = button

    def box(self):
        if enterPressed:
            if self.button is not None:
                self.button.autoclick()
```

Or maybe this one? :

```py
class Button:
    def _click(self):  # Maybe this method have events as parameters?
        return False

    def click(self):
        return self._click()

    def autoclick(self):
        def wrapper(*args):
            result = self._click(*args)  # This function needs events as it arguments
            if enterPressed:
                return True
            return result

        self.click = wrapper


class TextBox:
    def __init__(self, button=None):
        self.button = button

    def box(self):
        if self.button is not None:
            self.button.autoclick()
```

Comment: This worked in a sense. It sets button.click to True. But now i want it  to go back to  being a button object so it continues to serve as a button and not a boolean

Comment: @hippozhipos It sets `button.click` to a function returns `True`, not just boolean `True`. So you mean you want to turn back `button.click` to the state before wrapped by the decorator so that it becomes again a function returns `False`?

Comment: Yes that's what i meant.

Comment: @hippozhipos I updated my answer. I hope my guess would be right :)